# LLVM-IR syntax folding for Vim

Tags: vim, syntax, folding, llvm-ir

I am working with LLVM-IR code, generated by `clang -emit-llvm` and want to get code folding working.

So far I am using `foldmethod=expr` and `foldexpr=LLVMFold()`.
I would like to use syntax based folding (i.e. `foldmethod=syntax`) using the syntax file from the llvm repository. [Available here](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/utils/vim/llvm.vim).

Note that the first regex is from the syntax file for the label.

```
function! LLVMFolds()
    let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
    if match(thisline, '^[-a-zA-Z$._][-a-zA-Z$._0-9]*:') >= 0
        return ">2"
    elseif match(thisline, '^\}$') >= 0
        return "<1"
    elseif match(thisline, '{$') >= 0
        return ">1"
    else
        return "="
    endif
endfunction
```

Which gobbles the closing braces into the level 2 folds.

Also tried have been `foldmethod=indent` which didn't fold enough and `foldmethod=marker` with `foldmark="{,}"`
Ideally for this sample incomplete LLVM-IR code:

```
define i32 @main() nounwind {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4

for.cond:                                         ; preds = %entry
  %4 = load i32* %i, align 4
  %cmp1 = icmp slt i32 %4, 10
  br i1 %cmp1, label %for.body, label %for.end
}
```

I would like folds to be from the `{` of the `define` to the `}` and in each labelled section, i.e. from the `entry:` to the clear line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this function now

```
function! LLVMFolds()
    let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
    let nextline = getline(v:lnum + 1)
    " match start of global var block
    if match(thisline, '^@') == 0 && foldlevel(v:lnum - 1) <= 0
        return ">1"
    " match start of global struct block
    elseif match(thisline, '^%') == 0 && foldlevel(v:lnum - 1) <= 0
        return ">1"
    " matches lables
    elseif match(thisline, '^[-a-zA-Z$._][-a-zA-Z$._0-9]*:') >= 0
        return ">2"
    " keep closing brace outside  l2 fold
    elseif match(nextline, '^\}$') >= 0
        return "<2"
    " keep closing brace in l1 fold
    elseif match(thisline, '^\}$') >= 0
        return "<1"
    " open new l1 fold for open brace
    elseif match(thisline, '{$') >= 0
        return ">1"
    " for the next line being empty, close the fold for the var and struct blocks
    elseif match(nextline, '^$') >= 0
        if match(thisline, '^@') == 0 && foldlevel(v:lnum - 1) == 1
            return "<1"
        elseif match(thisline, '^%') >= 0 && foldlevel(v:lnum - 1) == 1
            return "<1"
        else
            return "="
        endif
    else
        return "="
    endif
endfunction
```

Which excludes the closing brace from the level 2 fold, and folds the initial lists of global structs and variables.

Comment: This, the syntax highlighting and an ftdetect are available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/EdJoJob/llvmir-vim)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that

```
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

is going to help with the syntax file in your link, since that file does not define any `fold` arguments.

Your `LLVMFolds()` function seems to do almost what you want, but (if I understand correctly) you do not want the fold to include the `}` line.  Maybe what you want is to make the previous line end the fold, like this:

```
function! Foo(lnum)
    let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
    let nextline = getline(v:lnum + 1)
    if match(thisline, '^[-a-zA-Z$._][-a-zA-Z$._0-9]*:') >= 0
        return ">2"
    elseif match(nextline, '^\}$') >= 0
        return "<1"
    elseif match(thisline, '{$') >= 0
        return ">1"
    else
        return "="
    endif
endfunction
```

This may or may not do what you want if there are no lines between `{` and `}`.  For testing purposes, try

```
:set fdm=expr foldexpr=LLVMFolds() fdc=5
```

References:

```
:help fold-syntax
:help :syn-fold
:help fold-expr
```

Comment: Is "RTFM" really necessary?

Comment: No, but I wanted to separate the three `:help` lines from the previous `:set` line, and I could not think of anything better.

Comment: Something as simple as "Manuals:", "Documentation:" or "You can learn more by reading the help pages" would have done. I know "RTFM" is common in some circles and some people wouldn't be offended by it, but many will.

Comment: The `nextline` was what I was needing. Solution to follow. Need to wait 8 hours as I'm new.

Comment: @jerry, I was taught that RTFM stands for "Read The Fine Manual," so it did not occur to me that it would bother anyone.  I will change it.  At first, I thought you were just complaining that it was redundant.