# Adding a marker for vim syntax folding

Tags: vim, syntax, folding

I usually code in C, and I have in my .vimrc `set foldmethod=syntax`, which works very well as it folds braces and comments and everything.

But sometimes I need to fold big chunks of code so that they don't get in my way (for example a group of related functions), and I usually do this with `set foldmethod=marker` and the markers `>>>` and `<<<`.

I have been trying to add a new sync region and the nearest thing I have come with is:

```
syn region cFoldMarkers start='>>>' end='<<<' containedin=cComment transparent fold
```

but this creates a mess as it somehow it matches with comments.

Is there a way of achieving both objectives? or should I give up of doing this with syntax and just set markers for braces, comments and my custom one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after... like 5 hours trying to do it with syntax folding, I have given up and changed to expression folding.

Following this question: [LLVM-IR syntax folding for vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986912/llvm-ir-syntax-folding-for-vim) I have created a folding function that more or less does what I want:

```
function! CFold()
    let this_line = getline(v:lnum)

    " Matching of braces
    if match(this_line, '}') >= 0
        return 's1'
    elseif match(this_line, '{$') >= 0
        return 'a1'
    " Matching of comments
    elseif match(this_line, '/\*') >= 0
        if match(this_line, '\*/$') == -1
            return 'a1'
        " Matching custom folding
        elseif match(this_line, '>>>') >= 0
            return 'a1'
        elseif match(this_line, '<<<') >= 0
            return 's1'
        endif
    elseif match(this_line, '\*/$') >= 0
        return 's1'
    endif
    return '='
endfunction

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=CFold()
```

Answer (score 1):

Plugin [syntaxMarkerFold](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/vim-syntaxMarkerFold) adds this functionality.

---

`containedin=cComment` means that whole region (whole fold) is contained in single comment; we want only markers to be in comments (two separate comments). 
<sub>Surprisingly enough, it matches markers not belonging to any syntax group too; it's also undesired behaviour for us.</sub>

By leaving only

```
syn region cFoldMarkers start='>>>' end='<<<' transparent fold
```

it finds start of region and folds it. But it doesn't have so much luck with the end, so Vim just folds to the end of file.

So we need to add matching comments to the RegExp of region (`\s*//.\{-}`) and for some pecultiar reason, define `matchgroup=Comment`

```
syn region cFoldMarkers matchgroup=Comment start='\s*//.\{-}>>>' end='\s*//.\{-}<<<' transparent fold
```

Now it should fold just where we want.

---

Of course, there are more edge cases, which require more handling. 
We would also like to be able to use any marker and different valid comments than just `//`. 
Not to mention leveled marker folding (e.g. `{{{1`).

Have a look at the code of my [syntaxMarkerFold](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/vim-syntaxMarkerFold/blob/master/plugin/syntaxMarkerFold.vim) plugin to check how I've resolved those issues.